# arr.push(newItem) VS arr = [...arr, newItem] где тут иммутабельность?

Tags: javascript

Обучаюсь сам и прохожу тему с иммутабельностью. Поставлена некая задача, где есть исходный массив и в него нужно добавить элемент (по условию желательно сделать это "иммутабельно"). И вот ситуация:

```
arr.push(newItem) //мутация
```

Очевидно мутабельная. И спикер предлагает сделать через spread оператор вот так:

```
arr = [...arr, newItem] //разве не мутация исходного массива?
```

Но ведь до старого массива нам попросту теперь не получить доступ по этой ссылке. То есть исходного массива больше нет, по ссылке arr теперь хранится новый массив с добавленным элементом. Не должны ли мы создать тогда новую переменную для хранения уже нового массива? Так как такое присваивание убивает суть иммутабельности (доступ к неизмененному исходному массиву), разве не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не должны. Но можете, конечно. На старый массив могут быть другие ссылки, и то, на что они указывают, останется неизмененным.